# Re-factoring map function so that a string is returned instead

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I have a React component that consumes the value `objects` - which gives us access to an array, but currently, using the map function is going to return an array of labels/ assistants as opposed to just one string value. Can anyone help out I would best refactor this code to reflect this change? The current implementation does return the correct values, but I'm just not sure its the right use of map.

```
const FirstRepeatAttributeLabelAssistant = ({ objects, className }: Props) => {
  if (objects.length === 0) {
    return null;
  }

  let label = objects[0].attributeCollection.questions.map((question) => {
    return question._contributions.label;
  });

  let assistant = objects[0].attributeCollection.questions.map((question) => {
    return question._contributions.assistant;
  });

  return (
    <StyledGroup as={Row}>
      <StyledLabelWrapper>{label}</StyledLabelWrapper>
      <Column size={12} />

      <Column>
        <StyledAssistantWrapper>{assistant}</StyledAssistantWrapper>
      </Column>
    </StyledGroup>
  );
};
```

This is the array in question:

[image]

So, I really just want to assign my values label & assistant to those in this array.

Current output when I `console.log(labely);`:

[image]

Comment: How do you want to convert an array of labels to a single string? What do you want to do with it? Concatenate it?

Comment: Perhaps my updated description will make the idea a little more clear? Basically want the "let label" to be equal to the string value as opposed to the array in the last screenshot.

Comment: If you're sure there will always be at least 1 question, do a `[0]` in the array, or a `questions[0]` insetad of the map. Usually map is to work with arrays. If you only want 1 element, then stop working with the array as soon as possible. Also, if you do this, remember to check it, like you did in the `if (objects.length === 0)`

Comment: tried updating to this:

  let label = objects[0].attributeCollection.questions((question) => {
    if (objects.length === 0) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return question[0]._contributions.label;
    }
  });

but getting "objects[0].attributeCollection.questions is not a function" - can you see where i'm going wrong?

Comment: More like: `objects[0].attributeCollection.questions[0]._contributions.label`. You want the label of the first question, so you first go to the first question, and then take its label. Same as what you did with `objects[0]`

Comment: thanks pal - I understand the thinking, I'm just having trouble making it work with the syntax:


let assistant = objects[0].attributeCollection.questions[0]._contributions.label => {
    return question._contributions.assistant;
  };


"Is not a function"

Comment: You don't need that function `=>`. That function is just the mapping of the `.map()`. If you don't have the map, you don't need it either. Just leave: `let assistant = objects[0].attributeCollection.questions[0]._contributions.assistant;`. As you see, what you had inside the map, you have it now after the `questions[0]`. Working in 1 element instead of working in an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236936/discussion-between-sicun-and-ivan).